# how to remove duplicate elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have recently started to learn programming in java and in the program below I'm trying to print distinct array elements Like e.G if an `int arr[]={2,5,4,9,3,2,5,9,4}` then I want to be able to get the numbers only once i.e.,

**expected value** 2 5 4 9 3

Below is my code to do this but I'm getting incorrect o/p

**My ouput:** 2 5 4 9.

Can anyone point me out what am I doing wrong

Comment: You can use a `LinkedHashSet` to prune duplicate items. See https://howtodoinjava.com/array/array-remove-duplicate-elements/

Comment: You are missing code. (You mentioned " below is my code" but we see none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer[] arr = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 };
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
ArrayList<Integer> distinct = new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Or

```
List<Integer> distinct = new ArrayList<>();
distinct.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
distinct.removeIf(t -> !set.add(t));
```

Test

```
System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(arr));
System.out.println("After: " + Arrays.toString(distinct.toArray()));
```

**Output**

Before: [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]

After: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it `old` style using a `Set` which can only store unique values:

```
    int arr[]={2,5,4,9,3,2,5,9,4};
    Set<Integer> uniq = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int x : arr) {
        uniq.add(x);
    }

    System.out.println(uniq);
```

**Output:**

`[2, 3, 4, 5, 9]`

Comment: That's an interesting method. Didn't know it even existed. Thanks, upvoted!

Comment: Thanks for the upvote.  Can learn a lot on SO.

Comment: By the way, will this maintain order?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done very simply via Streams with the `distinct()` method(in Java 8), like this:

```
    int arr[] = {2,5,4,9,3,2,5,9,4};
    arr = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().toArray();
    for (int i : arr) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
        // 2 5 4 9 3
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is one question that you would want to answer here**: *Do you want to return the distinct array elements in any order or in the same order as given in the initial array ?*

If you don't want the ordering then @Scary Womabart's answer is absolutely correct.

But if you want to maintain ordering then do the following: Use a **Set** for lookup. As you are new to programming, I am writing a detailed code so that you can learn as much as possible

```
public int[] getBackArrayWithoutDuplicatesMaintainingOrder(int[] arr) {
        Set<Integer> lookupSet = new HashSet<>();
        List<Integer> listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (lookupSet.contains(arr[i])) {
                continue;
            }
            listWithoutDuplicates.add(arr[i]);
            lookupSet.add(arr[i]);
        }
        int sz = listWithoutDuplicates.size();
        int[] newArray = new int[sz];
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            newArray[i] = listWithoutDuplicates.get(i);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Once you are adept at programming, then you can use **LinkedHashSet** to achieve the above as it maintains Ordering unlike **Set**